# Best method for persisting a list of model objects to a file

Tags: dart

This is a generalized question about a best practice in a Flutter app in Dart.

Consider I have a basic model.

```js
class Person {
  String fname;
  String lname;
  String phone;
  
  ...
  
}
```

This class has a lot of other public and private properties, but all of them are derived from these three public properties.  I want to persist a List{Person} to file but I only need to store these three public properties for each Person.

One idea I have is to create a Convert class that takes a Person and creates a simpler class that only has the three properties which gets persisted to the file.  The same Convert class would take the same simpler class and create a Person class.

Is this the best approach?

Does there happen to be a framework that does this for me?

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON. Add `toJson` to your class.

```
class Person {
  String fname;
  String lname;
  String phone;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'fname': fname, 'lname': lname', ... };      
}
```

Then you can use `jsonEncode` to get a String.

We have some packages to make creating the toJson/fromJson bits easier. See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable